# How to make a request to a website, which has user authentication, to access its contents?

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, server

I am working on an IOS app as my college project. Basically my college has a website which has login form[no sign up forms there], and students using their unique college ID and their own password can login into this website and access things like courses they have registered for, their grades etc. Now in my app i have a log in form and i want the students to be able to login with the same existing ID and password and access the same information as they would be able to do on the website itself. Simply speaking, i want to access the post authentication information on the website in my app. How do i approach this problem?

Comment: Hey there, are you using any framework to handle network connections on your Swift project? If so, please share what you've done so far.

Comment: I am just using Alamofire pod t make request, and the main issue is on what URL to make request using alamofire.

Answer (score 0):

It depends if your school server allows request from different origins (different domain). If, yes just check when you login what info it posts and to which address. Then send a request to this address with the same info and check the result from the request.

Example: 
Just use chrome or firefox dev inspector, fill the login form, send it and check the request done.

Let say the request done is a POST @ http://myschool.com/login with username and password form, and the result if successful is a 200 code and a cookie. Then in node js you could do:

```
const querystring = require('querystring');
const request = require('request');

const form = {
    username: 'usr',
    password: 'pwd',
};

const formData = querystring.stringify(form);
const contentLength = formData.length;

request(
    {
        headers: {
            'Content-Length': contentLength,
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        uri: 'http://myschool.com/login',
        body: formData,
        method: 'POST'
    }, 
    function (err, res, body) {
         // check the result here
    }
);
```

Comment: This help me in authenticating the user, but how will i get the post authentication details of the student, how will i get that stuff, do i have to request them seperately ?